# CommandHandler and EventHandler order

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs, command-pattern

I am new about CQRS and want to learn work order of the pattern. My command handler and command are like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

When I cerate a Work a command handler is working.

```
public class CreateWorkCommandhandler : ICommandHandler<CreateWork>
{
    public void Handle(CreateWork command)
    {
        Save to database...            
    }
}
```

And I do not call command handlers in controller classes. I use a `CommandExecuter` to call commands by type.

```
public class CommandExecuter
{

    public static void ExecuteCommand<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

        var handlers = serviceLocator.GetAll(handlerType);

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            ((dynamic)handler).Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```

I want to send email and send sms and another things after work created. But I can not do these steps in `Handle(CreateWork command)` because of separated architecture.

I think these steps are events, is this true? So I need `event` and `event handler` types.

```
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent event);
}
```

Where can I populate the events? In **CommandExecuter** or **CommandHandler** I need multiple events for an event. for example:

public class WorkCreated:IEvent{}

Send sms, send email.

Answer (score 4):

```
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        ((dynamic)handler).Handle((dynamic)command);
```

That looks *really* weird.  Why, in a [ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd)/[cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) context, would there ever be more than one handler for a command?

For an event message, that pattern could make sense; it is normal for an event to have zero or more subscribers.  But commands are message addressed to a specific target so enumerating a number of handlers seems odd.

On to your question

> I want to send email and send sms and another things after work created. But I can not do these steps in Handle(CreateWork command) because of separated architecture.
>
> I think these steps are events, is this true?

Events are messages that describe something that occurred in the past.  Does that sound like a match?  It seems to me that you are describing a command - you want some system to send an email for you.  That doesn't sound like something that has already happened?

EmailCommandSucceeded, SMSCommandFailed, and so on in finer detail -- *those* are events; something that happened in the past.

In [ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd), a command is a proposal to change the state of the domain (provided that the change is permitted by the business invariant enforced by the domain model).  The response from the model is usually in two parts; data to persist when committing the transaction (Repository.save()), and messages to share with the rest of the world.  These messages can be domain events, or commands to be run in other transactions/contexts.

So the usual answer to your question would be that the command handler would hand the command off to the domain model, and get back a list of commands to be scheduled (outside of the transaction context).

IF the command handler can't do this directly, an alternative might be to publish an EmailCommandScheduledEvent, and then have the event handler do the same work.

Comment: I agree that the foreach is not suitable for the handlers. It would be better to do handlers.single() to make sure that there is only one handler for the command.